# мероприятие НА отделении или В отделении?

Tags: согласование

Мероприятие прошло в педагогическом отделении колледжа или на педагогическом отделении колледжа?

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта звучат приемлемо. Однако, на мой взгляд, разница такова:

1) "мероприятие прошло В отделении" – имеется в виду конкретное помещение/здание, в котором расположено это отделение;

2) "мероприятие прошло НА отделении" – речь об отделении как о структурном образовании.

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже склонялась к предлогу  НА, но  всё же сомневалась. Ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Отделение в учебном учреждении является не структурной единицей, и название его отражает специализацию или научную направленность, как в вузах — кафедры и факультеты. Поэтому: на кафедре, на факультете, на отделении.